# How to pass Class object to CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, class, cuda

I am trying to pass a `Class` obj from host to device CUDA kernel. I am getting some error like `Bus error: 10`. Please help how to pass Class object that contains an `Array`. Here is my code.

1. `matrixCU.h`

   ```
   #ifndef __MATRIXCUDA_H__
   #define __MATRIXCUDA_H__
   #include <iostream>
   class Matrix{
       private:
       std::size_t height,width,sizeArray;
       double *array;

   public:
   __device__ __host__ Matrix();
   __device__ __host__ Matrix(std::size_t);
   __device__ __host__ Matrix(std::size_t,std::size_t);
   __device__ __host__ Matrix(const Matrix &);
   __device__ __host__ Matrix &operator=(const Matrix &mat);
   __device__ __host__ ~Matrix();
   __device__ __host__ void assignValue(std::size_t,std::size_t, double);
   __device__ __host__ void assignValue(std::size_t , double );
   __device__ __host__ void displayArray();
   };
   #endif
   ```
2. `matrixCU.cu`

   ```
           #include <iostream>
           #include"matrixCU.h"
           Matrix::Matrix(){
               height = 1;
               width = 1;
               sizeArray = height*width;
               array= new double[sizeArray];
               if (!array)
               {
                   //cout << "Memory allocation failed"<<endl;
                   printf("Memory allocation failed");
               }
           }

           Matrix::Matrix(size_t h){
               height = h;
               width = 1;
               sizeArray = height*width;
               array = new double[sizeArray];
               if (!array)
               {
                   //cout << "Memory allocation failed"<<endl;
                   printf("Memory allocation failed");
               }
           }

           Matrix::Matrix(size_t h,size_t w){
               height = h;
               width = w;
               sizeArray = height*width;
               array= new double[sizeArray];

               if (!array)
               {
                   //cout << "Memory allocation failed"<<endl;
                   printf("Memory allocation failed");
               }

           }

           Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &mat){
               height = mat.height;
               width = mat.width;
               sizeArray = mat.sizeArray;
               array = new double[sizeArray];

               for(size_t i = 0;i<sizeArray;++i){
               array[i] = mat.array[i];
               }

           //copy(mat.array,mat.array+mat.sizeArray,array);
           }

           Matrix &Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &mat){
               height = mat.height;
               width = mat.width;
               sizeArray = mat.sizeArray;
               array = new double[sizeArray];

               for(size_t i = 0;i<sizeArray;++i){
               array[i] = mat.array[i];
               }

               //copy(mat.array,mat.array+mat.sizeArray,array);
               return *this;
           }

           Matrix::~Matrix(){
               delete [] array;
           }
           void Matrix::assignValue(size_t i,size_t j, double value){
               size_t l = i*width + j;
               array[l] = value;
           }

           void Matrix::assignValue(size_t l, double value){
               array[l] = value;
           }

           void Matrix::displayArray(){
               size_t i,j,l;
               for(i=0;i<height;++i){
                   for(j=0;j<width;++j){
                       l =i*width + j;
                       //cout<<array[l]<<"\t";
                       printf("%f\t",array[l]);
                   }
                   //cout<<endl;
                   printf("\n");
               }
           }
   ```

and here is the main code

3. `main.cu`

   ```
           #include<iostream>
           #include"matrixCU.h"
           #include<curand_kernel.h>

           const int N=1000;

           __global__ void initialize(Matrix *R){
               int i= blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
               if(i<N){
                   curandState state;
                   curand_init(clock64(), i, 0, &state);
                   R->assignValue(i,curand_uniform(&state));
               }
           }

           int main(){
               Matrix R(N);
               Matrix *pR;
               pR=&R;
               cudaMallocManaged(&pR,N*sizeof(Matrix));
               initialize<<<4,256>>>(pR);
               cudaDeviceSynchronize();
               pR->displayArray();
               return 0;
           }
   ```

I compiled and run this code as
`nvcc -dc main.cu matrixCU.cu` and
`nvcc main.o matrixCU.cu` then `./a.out`

And I am getting the error like `Bus error: 10`. Please help, I am new to CUDA.

Comment: Where exactly do you get this error?

Comment: during `./a.out`

Comment: You can't use host-allocated memory (the stuff you got from `new`) in a kernel.

Comment: could you please explain this ?

Comment: You're also misunderstanding how the memory allocation works. To allocate device memory for an object of type `T`, you would `T* p = nullptr; cudaError_t error = cudaMallocManaged(&p, sizeof(T));` and if it succeeds, `p` holds the address of the allocated memory (but not of an object; the memory is unintialised). It's very similar to `T* p = malloc(sizeof(T));` in C.

Comment: @subratappt A CUDA kernel can only use memory that was allocated for kernel use through the CUDA API. `new` allocates host (CPU) memory. I suspect that you need to study some more before continuing.

Comment: I could not find any solution for this, can you help ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of problems with your code.  I'm not sure I will mention all of them, so study the differences between my files and yours.

1. If you want to allocate data that is usable on both host and device from host code, you must use `cudaMallocManaged`.  You cannot use host `new` operator (unless you have overloaded it for a specific class, which you haven't and is not possible for base classes like `double`).
2. Likewise you have to free those allocations using `cudaFree`.
3. Your host allocation of the R matrix is not correct.  You assigned `pR` to the address of `R`, which won't work, because R is not a managed allocation, and you then overwrote that with a call to `cudaMallocManaged`.  Just broken.
4. When we use `cudaMallocManaged`,  a class method using that cannot be marked `__device__`.  That API is only usable in host code.

The following represents the smallest number of changes I could make, covering the items above, to get your code working:

```
$ cat matrixCU.h
#ifndef __MATRIXCUDA_H__
#define __MATRIXCUDA_H__
#include <iostream>
class Matrix{
    private:
    std::size_t height,width,sizeArray;
    double *array;

public:
           __host__ Matrix();
           __host__ Matrix(std::size_t);
           __host__ Matrix(std::size_t,std::size_t);
           __host__ Matrix(const Matrix &);
           __host__ Matrix &operator=(const Matrix &mat);
           __host__ ~Matrix();
__device__ __host__ void assignValue(std::size_t,std::size_t, double);
__device__ __host__ void assignValue(std::size_t , double );
__device__ __host__ void displayArray();
};
#endif
$ cat matrixCU.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
        #include"matrixCU.h"
        Matrix::Matrix(){
            height = 1;
            width = 1;
            sizeArray = height*width;
            cudaError_t err = cudaMallocManaged(&array,sizeArray*sizeof(array[0]));
            if (err != cudaSuccess)
            {
                //cout << "Memory allocation failed"<<endl;
                printf("Memory allocation failed");
            }
        }

        Matrix::Matrix(size_t h){
            height = h;
            width = 1;
            sizeArray = height*width;
            cudaError_t err = cudaMallocManaged(&array,sizeArray*sizeof(array[0]));
            if (err != cudaSuccess)
            {
                //cout << "Memory allocation failed"<<endl;
                printf("Memory allocation failed");
            }
        }

        Matrix::Matrix(size_t h,size_t w){
            height = h;
            width = w;
            sizeArray = height*width;
            cudaError_t err = cudaMallocManaged(&array,sizeArray*sizeof(array[0]));

            if (err != cudaSuccess)
            {
                //cout << "Memory allocation failed"<<endl;
                printf("Memory allocation failed");
            }

        }

        Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &mat){
            height = mat.height;
            width = mat.width;
            sizeArray = mat.sizeArray;
            cudaError_t err = cudaMallocManaged(&array,sizeArray*sizeof(array[0]));
            if (err != cudaSuccess)
            {
                //cout << "Memory allocation failed"<<endl;
                printf("Memory allocation failed");
            }

            for(size_t i = 0;i<sizeArray;++i){
            array[i] = mat.array[i];
            }

        //copy(mat.array,mat.array+mat.sizeArray,array);
        }

        Matrix &Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &mat){
            height = mat.height;
            width = mat.width;
            sizeArray = mat.sizeArray;
            cudaError_t err = cudaMallocManaged(&array,sizeArray*sizeof(array[0]));
            if (err != cudaSuccess)
            {
                //cout << "Memory allocation failed"<<endl;
                printf("Memory allocation failed");
            }

            for(size_t i = 0;i<sizeArray;++i){
            array[i] = mat.array[i];
            }

            //copy(mat.array,mat.array+mat.sizeArray,array);
            return *this;
        }

        Matrix::~Matrix(){
            cudaFree(array);
        }
        void Matrix::assignValue(size_t i,size_t j, double value){
            size_t l = i*width + j;
            array[l] = value;
        }

        void Matrix::assignValue(size_t l, double value){
            array[l] = value;
        }

        void Matrix::displayArray(){
            size_t i,j,l;
            for(i=0;i<height;++i){
                for(j=0;j<width;++j){
                    l =i*width + j;
                    //cout<<array[l]<<"\t";
                    printf("%f\t",array[l]);
                }
                //cout<<endl;
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
$ cat main.cu
     #include<iostream>
        #include"matrixCU.h"
        #include<curand_kernel.h>

        const int N=1000;

        __global__ void initialize(Matrix *R){
            int i= blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
            if(i<N){
                curandState state;
                curand_init(clock64(), i, 0, &state);
                R->assignValue(i,curand_uniform(&state));
            }
        }

        int main(){
            Matrix R(N);
            Matrix *pR;
            cudaMallocManaged(&pR,sizeof(Matrix));
            *pR = R;
            initialize<<<4,256>>>(pR);
            cudaDeviceSynchronize();
            pR->displayArray();
            return 0;
        }
$ nvcc -rdc=true -o test matrixCU.cu main.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./test
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0.071004
0.881221
0.136314
0.365471
0.869905
0.786048
0.072587
0.977478
0.090027
0.784501
0.956906
0.886720
0.716731
0.990675
0.855763
0.572306
0.926382
0.088547
0.690107
0.693889
0.603796
0.380563
0.535087
0.162159
0.130997
0.791521
0.033966
0.186036
0.717896
0.737800
0.401380
0.298967
0.437803
0.783576
0.644548
0.180492
0.048909
0.058355
0.890834
0.822247
0.957458
0.464835
0.260732
0.765984
0.095627
0.696827
0.967914
0.648809
0.475668
0.724241
0.329649
0.651475
0.783935
0.061218
0.193391
0.731417
0.001546
0.057500
0.549647
0.923320
0.480090
0.780765
0.562150
0.415062
0.993346
0.619210
0.573613
0.788595
0.089867
0.126398
0.393461
0.031120
0.562209
0.860722
0.029709
0.020258
0.032154
0.959066
0.539097
0.051973
0.597740
0.309279
0.064356
0.165475
0.936288
0.936569
0.940147
0.809314
0.385906
0.737780
0.245182
0.617622
0.804020
0.075155
0.014515
0.142879
0.705339
0.163538
0.318771
0.065821
0.501200
0.488487
0.554761
0.026746
0.731280
0.591759
0.402278
0.027762
0.646197
0.483466
0.636325
0.958660
0.284055
0.688907
0.863734
0.177655
0.372774
0.309040
0.890085
0.892424
0.559866
0.890482
0.746828
0.664398
0.082499
0.519862
0.822739
0.930987
0.375726
0.761936
0.609439
0.508076
0.297762
0.831960
0.277791
0.810657
0.605123
0.454552
0.239150
0.983239
0.912615
0.724977
0.280365
0.738776
0.299132
0.011427
0.816369
0.101436
0.486195
0.969667
0.641677
0.891698
0.558882
0.872550
0.105379
0.161112
0.530537
0.366833
0.097867
0.121119
0.827264
0.533857
0.874313
0.405111
0.982588
0.191437
0.950727
0.036380
0.284657
0.344919
0.727332
0.086354
0.403660
0.156581
0.113123
0.909607
0.032325
0.993558
0.780771
0.189485
0.337643
0.368653
0.975085
0.607430
0.637252
0.102953
0.431206
0.505485
0.581307
0.674293
0.916469
0.334928
0.000439
0.364342
0.311674
0.824597
0.364305
0.624897
0.094010
0.244369
0.295886
0.686752
0.237741
0.418019
0.429948
0.808117
0.641755
0.874406
0.780955
0.843963
0.280321
0.644448
0.973191
0.656018
0.413099
0.666328
0.098870
0.488157
0.813085
0.310812
0.603307
0.935658
0.681021
0.730611
0.271459
0.618244
0.546704
0.420874
0.847286
0.837329
0.571176
0.162310
0.969490
0.814732
0.620176
0.285194
0.565309
0.827454
0.381201
0.354889
0.120400
0.559674
0.784813
0.784853
0.204673
0.026896
0.942334
0.191417
0.599667
0.623399
0.171693
0.664806
0.550268
0.182918
0.546951
0.515124
0.310977
0.626322
0.755771
0.814052
0.577685
0.921988
0.809203
0.880358
0.628649
0.826777
0.466531
0.522288
0.650234
0.642578
0.692523
0.925580
0.417366
0.744375
0.212205
0.100794
0.682757
0.349675
0.448193
0.763235
0.446690
0.626758
0.479309
0.966294
0.095116
0.247121
0.423500
0.694378
0.684999
0.436070
0.985427
0.124690
0.830675
0.523437
0.290435
0.477991
0.607785
0.583163
0.887029
0.594623
0.282790
0.981283
0.345953
0.132277
0.052429
0.419485
0.495071
0.716816
0.019688
0.046086
0.556042
0.175318
0.858782
0.587863
0.229087
0.248072
0.151296
0.930247
0.583634
0.200742
0.602250
0.243866
0.937832
0.964248
0.541182
0.566934
0.528167
0.455638
0.337338
0.915541
0.014845
0.812097
0.387962
0.814644
0.561018
0.446411
0.196474
0.529297
0.027990
0.143012
0.486798
0.501173
0.103471
0.492401
0.165220
0.262854
0.306416
0.891005
0.148543
0.488292
0.560061
0.139010
0.741020
0.592255
0.877501
0.094123
0.853003
0.953739
0.468713
0.038470
0.055537
0.785538
0.032234
0.653423
0.006316
0.742476
0.262429
0.538420
0.948191
0.422741
0.947780
0.118863
0.251957
0.491484
0.657505
0.467903
0.379952
0.670963
0.635206
0.218026
0.246661
0.019329
0.353579
0.738275
0.115951
0.245934
0.362565
0.339475
0.195376
0.287473
0.610410
0.711066
0.295927
0.602231
0.085744
0.783727
0.211958
0.558423
0.581048
0.840549
0.919790
0.908709
0.710892
0.142209
0.259798
0.358526
0.982587
0.729312
0.355643
0.972439
0.066963
0.766495
0.455677
0.335058
0.105249
0.347533
0.556705
0.642309
0.449140
0.237073
0.923077
0.855320
0.121969
0.686332
0.543143
0.281068
0.167924
0.207383
0.808131
0.665351
0.441563
0.628264
0.834018
0.730585
0.119630
0.214248
0.118301
0.998303
0.345904
0.907547
0.575551
0.498900
0.031708
0.056363
0.971347
0.048892
0.904331
0.728991
0.860126
0.929356
0.775998
0.082585
0.848793
0.491587
0.465580
0.839088
0.489764
0.559898
0.988726
0.166667
0.478742
0.314910
0.556671
0.903586
0.789367
0.084805
0.525357
0.010694
0.801187
0.924251
0.115619
0.222583
0.564765
0.777636
0.083258
0.432392
0.325102
0.051917
0.771337
0.244661
0.410936
0.067163
0.058883
0.206597
0.926144
0.910277
0.931427
0.318363
0.952857
0.262882
0.031549
0.853218
0.864200
0.740018
0.421445
0.778487
0.607826
0.383871
0.733917
0.054857
0.123307
0.403572
0.667892
0.978576
0.770972
0.148966
0.093849
0.434403
0.745678
0.680830
0.365104
0.548875
0.857006
0.027067
0.505060
0.684357
0.653154
0.978205
0.554004
0.933031
0.835429
0.261711
0.707497
0.453605
0.771771
0.133137
0.409224
0.719492
0.595178
0.835815
0.043639
0.688801
0.328865
0.211282
0.864362
0.353246
0.633998
0.189601
0.860122
0.732243
0.930049
0.330278
0.211297
0.553998
0.410360
0.145061
0.594688
0.753200
0.426088
0.311669
0.513507
0.599102
0.540097
0.907585
0.361541
0.925146
0.344398
0.091586
0.931670
0.868378
0.584575
0.161473
0.078835
0.599470
0.453735
0.649924
0.752617
0.717426
0.724703
0.007661
0.466130
0.082873
0.823317
0.803449
0.681720
0.247576
0.370960
0.685922
0.968702
0.972480
0.145600
0.215099
0.576238
0.529124
0.122174
0.873409
0.096452
0.688353
0.461451
0.220745
0.596305
0.654279
0.814172
0.485580
0.691178
0.284079
0.755656
0.640800
0.235559
0.526888
0.881339
0.464136
0.515479
0.701673
0.766042
0.748992
0.637216
0.680738
0.264244
0.513140
0.612362
0.219023
0.181888
0.942823
0.979810
0.007846
0.051845
0.153540
0.658704
0.163448
0.018833
0.150050
0.482700
0.766370
0.380305
0.718186
0.185659
0.397264
0.637206
0.896022
0.755381
0.171956
0.208321
0.472355
0.043897
0.557638
0.543795
0.281032
0.896003
0.226191
0.288041
0.203736
0.247533
0.891655
0.103003
0.533880
0.513406
0.023316
0.865172
0.909065
0.820183
0.889483
0.902325
0.808454
0.172596
0.595968
0.959205
0.763288
0.811832
0.094167
0.655713
0.570013
0.456017
0.335148
0.709506
0.197503
0.469100
0.036439
0.867685
0.866681
0.089328
0.758056
0.919974
0.540013
0.737209
0.245158
0.480957
0.119510
0.680165
0.473584
0.746352
0.812241
0.164265
0.645677
0.408948
0.646678
0.996313
0.266382
0.786109
0.102574
0.081793
0.042725
0.901320
0.903022
0.370827
0.116377
0.148513
0.641947
0.988185
0.534740
0.290124
0.488126
0.688406
0.635819
0.041061
0.488130
0.903068
0.805637
0.379594
0.060992
0.070235
0.245431
0.885446
0.459276
0.405332
0.170523
0.221524
0.351225
0.610599
0.098554
0.494537
0.714730
0.292618
0.753696
0.677983
0.279188
0.041242
0.177235
0.445418
0.486639
0.883625
0.439943
0.906762
0.611522
0.702600
0.192586
0.701352
0.902904
0.831730
0.171905
0.611947
0.043654
0.358982
0.896191
0.371733
0.387501
0.867840
0.474686
0.285156
0.948178
0.265145
0.383775
0.880716
0.178402
0.876509
0.651860
0.479228
0.395485
0.812722
0.714489
0.974786
0.843317
0.873842
0.649662
0.901662
0.018448
0.909130
0.557107
0.973801
0.833762
0.667875
0.445815
0.125707
0.032208
0.381092
0.854889
0.432165
0.842306
0.102883
0.488534
0.317390
0.106481
0.252802
0.537869
0.821866
0.402344
0.580133
0.548850
0.950169
0.729780
0.283909
0.878742
0.896967
0.542452
0.706111
0.201831
0.796350
0.573107
0.547780
0.693936
0.381239
0.896723
0.259790
0.462630
0.097504
0.392813
0.434247
0.338579
0.519444
0.936378
0.550385
0.080931
0.668805
0.794754
0.145421
0.657209
0.816712
0.183759
0.417871
0.377352
0.561842
0.531488
0.468831
0.398729
0.367924
0.105588
0.435630
0.272374
0.600957
0.175964
0.424843
0.474066
0.880879
0.860876
0.388000
0.075704
0.065552
0.394633
0.602822
0.926586
0.807954
0.539659
0.688340
0.677482
0.798851
0.787824
0.616043
0.187996
0.094416
0.093962
0.569587
0.165626
0.534022
0.328510
0.410343
0.932529
0.362764
0.567724
0.045575
0.035658
0.320007
0.510330
0.979675
0.550351
0.566846
0.636248
0.082698
0.037850
0.000394
0.604477
0.791728
0.061347
0.273769
0.112541
0.736046
0.388991
0.697102
0.048412
0.235050
0.178021
0.346823
0.033713
0.540851
0.009417
0.843037
0.493029
0.252058
0.233311
0.493194
0.110216
0.308569
0.877967
0.889423
0.185219
0.119037
0.066453
0.323729
0.736569
0.131080
0.276096
0.911724
0.174000
0.769194
0.016669
0.907405
0.544761
0.904297
0.050780
0.149629
0.979373
0.636944
0.742445
0.699408
0.468510
0.031924
0.504938
0.020986
0.024615
0.847139
0.182187
0.479723
0.315336
0.539866
0.289621
0.539520
0.798866
0.619036
0.565818
0.205962
0.947796
0.572376
0.128618
0.444346
0.429170
0.009642
0.543231
0.239307
0.684082
0.075309
0.903709
0.912572
0.125115
0.525312
0.973700
0.143969
0.368056
0.949429
0.228075
0.483487
0.660288
0.590635
0.968287
0.425279
0.540247
0.240592
0.728381
0.552722
0.470203
0.252317
0.225089
0.743435
0.918008
0.095599
0.423085
0.181413
0.532619
0.713325
0.283655
0.533130
0.667046
0.721132
0.019322
0.715479
0.456797
0.301829
0.829011
0.041646
0.005163
0.731412
0.121360
0.279593
0.905235
0.109898
0.697796
0.209563
0.330866
0.657715
0.427852
0.716525
0.588886
0.998937
0.376172
0.518517
0.027857
0.224398
0.532648
0.259146
0.898033
0.950872
0.935855
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Thank you sir, thanks a lot... I just read the article also [link](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/). Your answer and the article make everything clear.

Comment: Can I write different version of constructor, copy constructor etc for `host` and `device`  using `#ifdef __CUDA_ARCH__` then `device` constructor which will contain `new`, else the host code which will contain  `cudaMallocManaged` etc. `#endif`, so that I can call the class inside device code.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.  Why not just try it?  However, a `Matrix` object created on the device with in-kernel `new` operator will not be interoperable with the host.  That is, there would be no way to directly transfer that matrix object to the host.  You would have to copy that matrix object to some other matrix object that was created in host code, before you could transfer the contents to the host.

Comment: @RobertCrovella is there any semantic difference between passing an `int` to `Matrix` compared to `size_t`?

Comment: on linux, `int` is 32 bits (signed), `size_t` (on 64-bit linux, which is the only thing that matters currently) is 64-bits (unsigned).  But with respect to this code, I believe I am simply following the prompt given by OP's code.